# Grails Spring Security UI for grails 3.1 requires Java version 52

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

I have an application I am trying to deploy to Redhat Openshift.  I'm using Grails 3.1.16 and the newest builds of Spring Security and Spring Security UI.

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.2'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.0.2'
```

When trying to compile a war using JDK jdk1.7.0_80 I get the following:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.

  > grails/plugin/springsecurity/ui/RegistrationCodeController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (JAVA 8)

Is there any way to override the version that the plugin is looking for?  I can't even find where that is set in the plugin code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not using jdk8? anything specific ? (jdk7 is not supported anymore)

Comment: jdk8 isn't supported in Tomcat7 on Redhat Openshift.  By default everything does compile with JDK8, but then it doesn't work on the server that is running JDK7.

Comment: Before downgrading, why not tomcat 8 ? or tomcat 8.5 ?

Comment: Again, Openshift doesn't support anything above Tomcat 7.  I"m looking at other hosting options right now that do support Tomcat 8.

Comment: Create an issue. http://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui. Edit: looks like it has already been reported. https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/issues/72